# How to get siblings in different DIVs or SPANs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have a number of forms on a page, like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="someID1">
    <div>
        <span>
            <input type="submit" class="submitClass">
        </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="someClass" value="name1">
    </div>
</form>

<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="someID1">
    <div>
        <span>
            <input type="submit" class="submitClass">
        </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="someClass" value="name1">
    </div>
</form>
```

Then I have some JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        console.log("page loaded");

        jQuery(".submitClass").on("click", function() {
            var id = jQuery(this).siblings("input[name='id']").val();
            var name = jQuery(this).siblings("input[name='name']").val();

            console.log(id);
            console.log(name);

            return false;
        });
    }
);
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sEXg3/

When the submit button is clicked, I want to stop the form from being submitted and get the values of the two inputs I have next to the submit button.

I tried doing this with the `.siblings()` function, but it doesn't work since the inputs are in different DIVs/SPANs (if I put them all right next to each other, it does work).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: On a separate note, I feel like you have way too much markup for this. Why not just http://jsfiddle.net/vmtkU/ ?

Comment: @Danny - Because this is a watered down example and if you remove the spans and divs (as you did), then my JS code works (where in my real application it does not, because of the spans and divs)

Comment: _"How to get siblings in different DIVs or SPANs?"_ - If they're in different DIVs or SPANs (or parents) they're not siblings.

Comment: @nnnnnn - apparently I don't understand the definition of "sibling" :-) Now that you mention it, I'm confused on what a parent is, too, because .parent() on the submit button returns the form, not the span or div it's inside.

Comment: No, the `.parent()` of the submit button is definitely the span, as in this updated version of your demo (click either submit button): http://jsfiddle.net/sEXg3/16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements you are looking for are not the sibling of the submit button.

In your case I would suggest to find the form element (you can find the form element in which the clicked button is present using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)) and them find the desired inputs fields inside it using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    console.log("page loaded");

    $(".submitClass").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $form = $this.closest('form');
        var id = $form.find("input[name='id']").val();
        var name = $form.find("input[name='name']").val();

        console.log(id);
        console.log(name);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2HdwF/)

Answer (score 3):

Since your .submitClass is placed in div and in span it's not a sibling of the other inputs... you can try something like this: **([Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sEXg3/9/))**

```
var id = jQuery(this).closest('form').find("input[name='id']").val();
var name = jQuery(this).closest('form').find("input[name='name']").val();
```

You first look for the parent form, then inside it look for the input fields.. an even more efficient version will be:

```
var $form = jQuery(this).closest('form');
var id = $form.find("input[name='id']").val();
var name = $form.find("input[name='name']").val();
```